# Symmetry painting

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor, mirror

Ok so I've been painting this model for a client, while also using symmetry. But for some reason texture image that contains color didn't mirror everything I did, even though on the viewport it mirrored just fine. I am unsure as to why this is happening and I couldn't find a solution to it online. Is there a way to transfer color data from the model on the right to the texture image on the left, to "refresh it" so to say? Do I need to repaint it? Manually mirror the texture in Photoshop? What should I do?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what happens if you delete the bad half, use a Mirror modifier to get the good half mirrored, and apply the Mirror modifier? The UVs should overlap, no? (Keep the original somewhere)

Comment: I cant even select it. When I try to select either side of the model, it just selects the same half on the UV map.

Comment: Instead of deleting one part of the mesh, you have to just enable symmetry painting.

Comment: Ok so, it doesn't change a thing. But what I just noticed is that no matter if symmetry painting is on or off, my stokes still mirror for some reason.